# role of IF (length($_)) statement in perl script

Tags: perl

I'm going through some Perl scripts I wrote some time ago to pseudocode them. A friend helped with writing this script, but I was wondering if someone could tell me the role of the IF (length($_)) statement? Here's the whole script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $inDataset = 0;

while(<>)
{
    chomp;
    s/\s*\\$//;
    if(/________/) 
    {
       $inDataset = 1;
    }
    elsif(/-------/) 
    {
        $inDataset = 0;
    }
    elsif($inDataset == 1) 
    {
        if(length($_))
        {
            ProcessData($_);
        }
    }
}

sub ProcessData
{
   my ($line) = @_;
   my @fields = split(/\s+/,$line);

   if($fields[3] =~ /p\.(...)(\d+)(...)/)
   {
      my $native = $1;
      my $resnum = $2;
      my $mutant = $3;

      print "$fields[1] $native $resnum $mutant\n"; 
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Note: The if statement also could'be been written as `if (length) {` as `length` will automatically work on `$_` when called without an argument.  All of this info could just be found in the documentation: [`length`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`length($_)` returns the [`length`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html) in characters of `$_`.

`if ( length($_) )` evaluates to true if `length($_)` is defined and non-zero. So the conditional in your code runs `ProcessData($_)` only if `$_` has characters.

Comment: Which means that it causes blank lines to be ignored (skipped).